# What do scipy.integrate.ode.integrate() optional `step` and `relax` arguments do?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

It's clear to me how to use the `scipy.integrate.ode.integrate(t)` function in its most simple form, but the API reads that it also takes two optional arguments, namely `step` and `relax`. The current [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.integrate.html#scipy.integrate.ode.integrate) has no information about these arguments, nor are they used in the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html). I am wondering, what do they do and what are some cases where they are useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `step` and `relax` arguments exist to allow the user to run just portions of the integration algorithm rather than the full integration. They are useful for testing the internals of the algorithm, but not particularly useful to the average user.

Both arguments are treated as boolean flags to choose a different type of partial integration. If `step` is True (nonzero), then `integrate()` runs the `step()` method of the integrator, whose docstring says `"""Make one integration step and return (y1,t1)."""` Basically it runs just a single step in the normal integration process.

If `relax` is True (nonzero), then `integrate()` runs the `run_relax()` method of the integrator, whose docstring says `"""Integrate from t=t0 to t>=t1 and return (y1,t)."""` Basically, it runs the integration until it passes the desired value, but doesn't do the extra back-step to the specified value.

This all can be seen in the [`IntegratorBase` source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/_ode.py#L632).

---

Edit: I opened a Pull Request in SciPy to clarify these docs: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7320/

Comment: Does that mean that `step=False` throws out all intermediate steps by default? Also, what do you mean by back-step - is that simply an interpolation? Both seem like strange behaviors if you're running the `integrate` method in a loop as done in the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html). In the first case, you're losing lots of useful information, and potentially re-doing lots of work unnecessarily. In the second case, you're accumulating error from interpolation. Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Yes, ``step=False`` throws-out intermediate results in the algorithm, and yes, the back-step is an interpolation. If you're really interested in the details of the algorithm, I'd suggest reading the [VODE source code](http://www.netlib.org/ode/vode.f). ``step=True`` is equivalent to setting ``ITASK=2``, and ``relax=True`` is equivalent to setting ``ITASK=3``.

Comment: I'm primarily interested in fully understanding the API rather than the implementation details. Plus, there are other integrators that can be used in place of vode, like lsoda or dopri5.

Comment: OK, then just stick with the first sentence of that response :) If all you're concerned with is the API, then you can safely ignore ``step`` and ``relax``, because they only exist to allow the user to explore the internals of various implementations.

Comment: In other words, for normal use, you shouldn't change the default values of ``step`` and ``relax``. The fact that you wanted to dig-in to their meaning made me think you were interested in implementation details.

Comment: The key word is *fully* understand the API :) The rest of the answer does that for me (to within the follow-up clarifications). Since that was my original question, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: I disagree -  I now understand that running `step=False` in a loop the way it's done in the example takes N steps forward, and then interpolates a fraction of a step back. The back-step adds an error which I would like to avoid, so I will try running with `step=True.` Furthermore, since I don't care about the exact final point but rather the trajectory of the system over time, I can even set `relax=True` to avoid the final back-interpolation. So for my use (not sure if it's normal) they are very useful parameters to know.

Comment: OK, but be aware that ``step=True`` will do some strange things: in particular, if you ask for a step to time ``t``, it will only go part-way there, and unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't give you access to the actual time corresponding to the end of that single step. Like I said, I don't think it's all that useful for anything but exploring the internals of the implementation.

Comment: Also if you set ``step=True``, then the value of ``relax`` is not referenced. You can't do both at once, because they're completely different calls to the underlying Fortran routine. If you're using the integrator to solve a problem, I'd suggest leaving both ``step`` and ``relax`` at their default values.

Comment: That is also very useful to know. I'd classify that information under "API." It would be nice to also have that in the docs.